# How to instantiate Spring-Integration's service-activator programmatically (not using xml file) in code?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a need to use service-activator. I want to bind it to input and output channel at run-time and not at development or deployment time. Hence cannot go with XML based service-activator instantiation. I am declaring exchanges and queues during program execution. Hence there is a need to instantiate service-activator dynamically during program execution.

I want to achieve the following but with code and not XML:

```
<service-activator input-channel="exampleChannel" output-channel="replyChannel"
                   ref="somePojo" method="someMethod"/>
```

What is the equivalent code for the above XML snippet? It seems that there is no ServiceActivator class in Spring-Integration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class for you - `ServiceActivatingHandler`. 
But it won't be so easy to do it at runtime. 
Of course you can simply provide to constructor of that class your POJO and its method.
Further and important option is `outputChannel`.
And here you should somehow provide `BeanFactory` infrastructure: `beanFactory`, `beanClassLoader` properties etc.
Call its `afterPropertiesSet()`.
And the main goal - **subscribe** that handler to the `exampleChannel`.
It depends on type of that channel. If it is **direct** one or **executor**, it will be just enough to build `EventDrivenConsumer`.
But if it **queue** you should build `PollingConsumer`.

It's just a draft how to achieve your task and there may be something else to build for complex solution.

Comment: ServiceActivatingHandler has no method to set input channel. Is there a way to set input channel? In my scenario, I think, it is better not to use Service-Activator and go with channels and message-handlers. What do you suggest?

Comment: Could you please point me to the code file where ServiceActivatingHandler is being instantiated by the framework when it is processing the <service-activator> node?

Comment: I said: to subscribe to the  input channel, you have to wrap ServiceActivatingHandler to the PollingConsumer or EventDrivenConsumer. Re. code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/config/xml/ServiceActivatorParser.java. And right: you can use MessagingTemplate directly

Answer (score 4):

This question is already answered but i think an example might do good.

```
public class NoContextExample {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NoContextExample.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //register an input channel
    SubscribableChannel inputChannel = new DirectChannel();
    //register a service-activator message handler
    ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(new somePojo(),"someMethod");
    //set service activator as a handler for input channel
    inputChannel.subscribe(serviceActivator);

    //register an output channel
    SubscribableChannel outputChannel = new DirectChannel();
    //set the service activator's output channel to outputChannel
    serviceActivator.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
    //register a message handler for output channel
    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(){
                                 @Override
                                 public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException{
                                    logger.info("MessageChannel.handleMessage ["+message.getPayload()+"]");
                                  }
                              };
    //subscribe message handler to output channel
    //this is equivalent to EventDrivenConsumer consumer = new EventDrivenConsumer(outputChannel, handler);
    //and then doing consumer.start(); then inputChannel.send(); then consumer.stop();
    outputChannel.subscribe(handler);

    // we are now ready to send the message on input channel
    inputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("World"));

}
```

}